# What is Low Level Plumbing in Programming field?

Tags: java

As per **Oracle Java Documentation**  Collections Framework frees you to concentrate on the important parts of your program rather than on the low-level "plumbing" required to make it work.I want to know :

1. What is Low-level Plumbing error?
2. I want a example of small code that shows, how java collection help us to    overcome of this error or problem. or Real time example. Thanks in advance

Comment: Low Level Plumbing is just an expression IIRC.

Comment: The only references I can find are related to [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma).

Comment: Collections Framework frees you to concentrate on the important parts of your program rather than on the low-level "plumbing" required to make it work. what is the exact meaning of this ? @Andrew Li

Comment: Ah, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/) it is.

Comment: :) yes Shmosel.. can you give me the example. plss

Comment: @Sniffer "low level plumbing" here is just an expression or allusion that essentially means "the lower level dirty work". In this context, the Collection Framework allows you to concentrate on more important parts of the program instead of the lower level dirty work that may be confusing and *dirty* /overly complex. This is my interpretation

Comment: Plumbing is just another term for code,  Low Level Code like basement plumbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple answer to your question.

In Collection Framework, java provides us with awesome inbuilt Data Structures and Algorithms, so that you do not have to implement them on your own. Just concentrate on your Business logic, while java provides you with cool features on which you do not have to concentrate. 
**For example**,
1. you have to sort, just use Collections to sort your values. 
2. Let's say HashMap. It is somewhat difficult to make your own HashMap implementation. So why re-invent the wheel? Use them and they are even more optimized in case of performance.

*In short, Collections framework makes your life easy.*

 And it(low level plumbing) is not an error.

Comment: Thanks Tahir Hussain Mir .. Worth Example for me. Now I clearly understand the Low level pumbing and Importance of Java Collections.

Comment: still someone downvoted my answer.
Anyways, my pleasure dear. @Sniffer

Answer (score 0):

It is just a phrase that means Low level efforts or more specifically low level coding. E.g. Unlike C++, Java doesn't require you to do the low level plumbing of pointers and memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks VHS. But I want more specific answer...

Comment: Moderators need to find out Mr. Downvoter who's downvoting everyone's answers for no reason.